# Mongoid: Dynamically Keyed Statically defined embedded classes with validations and callbacks

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I'm fairly familiar with Mongoid and Ruby and have used Mongoid for several large applications in a production system. However, I find myself a bit stumped at this issue.

The title is probably a bit head scratching so let me give an example JSON:

```
{
  "could_be_anything": {
    "key": "something",
    "value": "something else"
  },
  "some_other_runtime_value": {
    "key": "another",
    "value": "another something"
  },
  // ... ect
}
```

So the key for the object could be anything, however the data inside is structured and needs validations like presence of key and value.

The only way I can think to do it is to take a block of code which represents the class definition of the embedded object, and dynamically create a new class and class_eval it with the block of code. I guess I could use after_initialize and after_find to look at all attributes and hook things together that way.

Is there no simpler way?

Comment: Aren't you really just using a semi-freeform Hash field? If so, wouldn't you just validate the Hash like any other field?

Comment: Yes you could do that, but that would involve performing the validation from the top level, and if it were deeply nested it could get quite tedious. You loose the context of self when you do that, no longer can you make a simple addition to the class like validation of presence or integer length, regexes are all lost. Additionally, callbacks are gone and Mongoid's dirty tracking is a rats nest since when a leaf node changes the entire structure is marked as changed.